# HQL querying different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

I'm querying my table Airport for rows where the name is 'term%' and order it by name. It looks like this and it works fine:

```
from Airport where name like 'term%' order by name
```

Now I want to look for 'term%' in the column city in the same query, but I can't get it to work.
I would like to have something like this, but it's not right:

```
 from Airport where name like 'term%' or where city like 'term%' order by named
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one `where` :

```
from Airport where name like 'term%' or city like 'term%' order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Query should be

```
from Airport where name like 'term%' or city like 'term%' order by name
```

instead of

```
from Airport where name like 'term%' or where city like 'term%' order by named
```

Use only one `where` clause and its `name` not `named`